# "failed to open this device: LIBUSB_ERROR_ACCESS" on ubuntu16.04, have tried some solutions

Tags: linux, usb

After searching for long time on internet I think there is no proper answer so I put up this problem. As being new here, I apology if I made any mistakes.
I have a tof camera connected to ubuntu16.04 through usb and a software to operate it. When I try to receive the image through software:

```
./smartTOFViewer
```

it gives these error repeatedly:

`2018/07/06 20:27:20.297[3249948416][DBG] [dmcam_dev_open] open dmcam device @ 0x7f8ab88e29c0
2018/07/06 20:27:20.297[3249948416][DBG] [_usb_ll_dev_open]  create usb context
2018/07/06 20:27:20.300[3249948416][ERR] [dmcam_dev_open] open device failed!
2018/07/06 20:27:21.301[3249948416][DBG] [dmcam_dev_open] open dmcam device @ 0x7f8ab88e29c0
2018/07/06 20:27:21.301[3249948416][DBG] [_usb_ll_dev_open]  create usb context
2018/07/06 20:27:21.303[3249948416][ERR] [dmcam_dev_open] open device failed!
2018/07/06 20:27:22.304[3249948416][DBG] [dmcam_dev_open] open dmcam device @ 0x7f8ab88e29c0
2018/07/06 20:27:22.304[3249948416][DBG] [_usb_ll_dev_open]  create usb context
2018/07/06 20:27:22.307[3249948416][DBG] [_usb_ll_dev_open] found dmcam device (speed=3) @ 001:002:020
2018/07/06 20:27:22.307[3249948416][WRN] [_usb_ll_dev_open]   failed to open this device: LIBUSB_ERROR_ACCESS, try next ...
2018/07/06 20:27:22.308[3249948416][ERR] [dmcam_dev_open] open device failed!`

but if I run this command：

```
sudo ./smartTOFViewer
```

it works normally. So I think it's a permission issue, and create a udev rule file:

```
sudo nano /etc/udev/rules.d/99-persistent-usb.rules
```

and content:

```
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb",ATTRS{idVendor}=="111b", \
ATTRS{idProduct}==1238",GROUP="root", OWNER="root", \
MODE="0666"
```

The idVendor and idProduct are checked with:

```
$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8001 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 8087:07dc Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 064e:920b Suyin Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 046d:c530 Logitech, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 021: ID 111b:1238  
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I also tried setting something:

```
GROUP="dongtu" or "adm" or "usrs" or "plugdev", 
OWNER="dongtu" or just removing it,
adding TAG+="uaccess",
putting in one line and remove " \"
```

I run this command for reload:

```
sudo udevadm control --reload
```

However, all these make no change. I observed that there is no change under /dev/ when I connect the tof, but I failed to figure out why.
I hope to do my job in anaconda with python, which means I can't use sudo in case run under system python environment. Is there any one could help me? Apologize again if I wasted your time.

Comment: I thought it was SUBSYTEM singular but I do see the plural in the documentation too. You could try `udevadm info` or `test` which might help you check the rules? I assume if you 'ls -la' the device then the permissions haven't changed.

Comment: @Rup I searched for use of `udevadm info` and `udevadm test`, it seems that path `/dev/` is needed for a certain device, but as I mentioned there's nothing change under `/dev` when I connected the tof.  May be this is the problem?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I thought you meant no change when connecting after reloading the rules. If you don't have a /dev device for the camera then you might not be able to solve this with udev. (Unless e.g. it's temporarily creating a /dev entry, opening it and then deleting it again whilst still holding the inode?) I'd suggest digging through smartTOFViewer to see how it's accessing the device.

Comment: @Rup I would like to dig into smartTOFViewer, but it's packaged. Luckily I found the origin problem can be avoid by logging in as root. Anyway I will try to figure out what happened in /dev. Thank you for your advice:）